# how to stream audio data to my website in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtmp

I want to develop an application(like ZELLO) where users register on my server and want to make audio and video call to each other, Using any Protocol RTMP,RTSP, SIP SERVER, whatever.
But what i need is procedure that, how to make call and record data in my server.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from something called [Wowza Streaming Engine](https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine) as your centre piece.

And then you can setup a bridge using [siprtmp](https://code.google.com/archive/p/siprtmp/).

I would suggest for you to lookup [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org) technology, because you can simplify some of the moment of using wowza+siprtmp stack.

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Best Regards,

Eugene

Comment: sir, i just need a simple app like a user sing in(Registered) and add friend in his circle now he would be able to make a call to any of his added friend, is it possible with Wowza Stream Engine, and i need to record the call time data etc in my website. I don't how to start and how it is possible, currently i can develop website but i don't know how to integrate Wowza etc in android and php website. I am just new

Comment: Hey @PirFahimShah that's fine. You probably want to start by looking for Flash RTMP tutorials. For example you can get the flash player (open source) and extend it for your needs: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html

Comment: or you can move in another direction and learn Java to do a server side coding on wowza server to direct streams over TCP/UDP protocols to browser using RTC/WebRTC streams.

In any case you are looking at several months of studying.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, What actually Viber and whatsapp use for the audio calling?. Is there not any protocol or API, which i could used inside my android application and i would be able to make audio call from one user to other like VIBER making call between friends

Comment: well, neither viber or skype or other big vendors are not using SIP for this but a custom protocols. you might want to start with a SIP server, so that would allow you to get the commutation end point for the different calls, and then you'll need to learn how to perform conference calls for the users smoothly. Take a look here: http://www.asterisk.org

Also as you already guessed, there is NO open-source solution available that clones Zello features exactly.